# Android phone's microSD not useable by Windows 8, after using under Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, android, sd-card, usb-drive

I connected my Android phone (as 'mass storage') to **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**. It has a microSD card with fat32 filesystem. Thereafter I logged it to Windows and connected, but my Windows 8 didn't recognise it. It shows the card as a new drive, but when I double click it says *corrupted file system, do you wish to repair files*; I cannot use or open files in it.

Then I logged into Ubuntu again, card works properly under Ubuntu.

To solve this I formatted the card by logging into windows, so it worked. But again when I connected it to Ubuntu (where it worked) and then to Windows on a different PC it shows same error.

Why does card not open in Windows, if opened with Ubuntu, but works properly on Ubuntu itself no matters what. Seems like Ubuntu is altering file system of card.

Please help solving this so that I can use my microSD card without any trouble on any OS.
I have Android 4.4.2

Comment: **What version of Android are you using?** *This is a known 'Windows' issue, and can occur for any external/removable media.* Better results may be achieved by formatting the microSD media, using Android (and not Windows). However, it is the 'mass storage' access method that is allowing media to get confused. You need to be using (latest) MTP method instead.

Comment: @david6 My version of Android is 4.4.2 Kitkat, is MTP media transfer protocol or something else ?

Comment: **Yes.** You should not be having these issues with MTP. *Did you try re-formatting the media (using Android phone)?*